# JSF process validation with JSR 303

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

In our JSF application we use Hibernate bean validation framework to do bean class validation. By my understanding, bean validation fired during JSF process validation life cycle.  Since JSF process validation life cycle runs before update model, how it is possible that bean validation fired against model object, whose field values have not been set yet?

Am I wrong? When class level bean validation fired in JSF life cycle?

Thanks

Comment: I gather you're talking about the upcoming JSF 2.3 as class level bean vaildation is not available yet in current JSF 2.2 version? In case you didn't know, JSF 2.3 is currently still in beta (you can confirm it by seeing `mXX` suffix in JAR file names, standing for "milestone").

Comment: Thanks Balus, sorry, I missed, we are using omnifaces validateBean, which use copy of model,  pre - populated with submitted data. I had answer.